# Asymmetric Cryptography in PCL Project

Tags: mono, cryptography, xamarin, mvvmcross, portable-class-library

I want to create a service to encrypt and decrypt with any asymmetric encryption. So, basically I will have a public and a private key and I will have:

```
public interface ICryptoService
{
    byte[] Encrypt(byte[] byteToEncrypt, int asymetricKey);
    byte[] Decrypt(byte[] byteToDecrypt, int asymetricKey);
}
```

But, in my CorePCL project, with Profile 78 (.netFramework45+wphone8+monodroid+monotouch) I can't add a reference to System.Security.Cryptography.

How can I add a reference to any DLL or portable package to give me support for PCL 78 to use any asymmetric encryption? Any clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also try [PCL Crypto](https://github.com/aarnott/pclcrypto).  It's more recent and actively maintained than PCL Contrib.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the [pclcontrib](http://www.nuget.org/packages/PclContrib-API/) project which provides a lot of the System.Security.Cryptography name space.

Answer (score 1):

There's also [BouncyCastle PCL](https://github.com/onovotny/BouncyCastle-PCL) Which is pcl port of the .net port of the Java Library Bouncy Castle.